# webservice that returns JSON data

Tags: asp.net, json, web-services

I have tiered of Googling but did't get any clue for myself.
I want to make a web service which will have any method (let say-ProductInfo) & when i pass 
a productId in this method this will return the entire information of Product(like-ProdName,ProdPrice etc) in JSON format(File is downloaded with the Information of product).

I am very new ....so please guide me as a beginner for the above.
for any kind of help Millions of Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base on your tag. I guess you use ASP.NET MVC. however, it you mean class ASP.NET then you might need to use WCF-REST to return JSON.

So: for you starting point

- ASP.NET MVC - look at JsonResult [here >>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410269.aspx)
- ASP.NET - look at WCF-REST[here >>](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/sridhar_subra/116/Default.aspx)

Or if you are very new and don't know where to start, I'm recommended you to start at [ASP.NET MVC 2](http://www.asp.net/mvc)

Comment: Hi thanks again.. But i have problem.. i have gone through...ASP.NET - look at WCF-RESThere >> It is creating the service (localhost:2456/HTTPServiceJquery/service/…) but how i will access the methods of this service?? when i do this- (localhost:2456/HTTPServiceJquery/service/…) It results into method not allowed. so i want to use this methos of the service...plz tell me how i will do this. Sorry if it is a stupidity ...but i am anable to do this.
I want something in this manner-
http://209.62.6.226/GracoRest/service.svc/Rest/WheretoBuy

Comment: No, You're not stupid. everyone passed this. You must create WCF inside you ASP.NET project. because JSON/Javascript request not allow you to call cross-domain.

Comment: would you refer me some link(help) that will help me for doing this step by step.
Thanks again.

Comment: Unfortunally, There is no easy way - step by step that i can find. but first you need to have .svc in your project configure with web.config. 
http://www.itscodingtime.com/post/The-different-ways-to-host-a-WCF-Service-Application-in-a-Web-App.aspx might help. then you need to use Attribute WebInvoke which all good resource you can read at - http://www.west-wind.com/Weblog/ShowPosts.aspx?Category=WCF

I encourage you to use WCF because later on it will be what all use can use. Silverlight, jQuery, WinPhone7 etc.

Comment: Hi Jirapong...
I have solved my problem discussed above.
But now there is one other....
I have a method in my wcf service "ProductDetails" which takes 1 argument productId(string)...which returns product details to me.
This methos is working fine when i do-
http://192.xxx.xxx.xx./Abc/Service.svc/ProductDetails
It returns a file with contents in JSON format.
now i want to call this method in Iphone....i m doing this-
NSString *url=[NSString stringwithFormat:@"http://192.xxx.xxx.xx./Abc/Service.svc/ProductDetails/%@","@P2"]
Let the value of prodId is P2....This does't give me the right output.

Comment: so please suggest something for the above..where i m doing wrong.

Comment: There are two things.

1. You need to make Http Call instead of like that - http://www.mobileorchard.com/tutorial-json-over-http-on-the-iphone/
2. You need a JSON Library - Go here and do Option 1 http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/wiki/InstallationInstructions

Answer (score 1):

For [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324.aspx) (which is the recommended way of developing web service on .NET) you may take a look at [this article](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/ajax/JSON-EnabledWCFServicesInASPNET35.aspx) for an example of developing a web service exposing JSON data.

For plain old ASMX services you could use the [`[ScriptService]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.services.scriptserviceattribute.aspx) attribute. Here's [another article](http://encosia.com/2010/05/31/asmx-scriptservice-mistake-invalid-json-primitive/) which illustrates the concept with an example.

Comment: I want output something like in this manner-
http://209.62.6.226/GracoRest/service.svc/Rest/WheretoBuy

Comment: So the links I've posted might help you get started. Don't hesitate to ask if you encounter problems implementing some specific part.

Comment: Hi darin....
please help me for this.
I have a method in my wcf service "ProductDetails" which takes 1 argument productId(string)...which returns product details to me.
This methos is working fine when i do-
http://192.xx.x.xx./Abc/Service.svc/ProductDetails
It returns a file with contents in JSON format.
now i want to call this method in Iphone....i m doing this-
NSString *url=[NSString stringwithFormat:@"http://192.xx.x.xx./Abc/Service.svc/ProductDetails/%@","@P2"]
Let the value of prodId is P2....This does't give me the right output.
so please something for the above..where i m doing wrong.